# Finding where a shortcode comes from

Tags: shortcode

I have to change a few things in a page that I have not created. I have to insert some text inside a contact form. When I go to edit that page all I see is some shortcode. It's a custom shortcode that looks like [companyName_apply_form]. I have no idea where it comes from. It's not coming from the contact form plugin that created the other contact forms in the page and I also can't find anything in the template files. Any idea where a custom shortcode like that may come from?

Comment: Has another developer worked on this site? If so, it may be a custom plugin, located in either the `wp-content/plugins` or `wp-content/mu-plugins` directories. The shortcode could also be registered by a custom theme. In short, such a shortcode could come from virtually any 3rd-party extension to your site.

Comment: Yes it was made by a developer before me that we have no contact with. Thanks for the leads, I'll check those directories.

Comment: There is a plugin that works 95% of the time : Shortcode Finder. But direct searching the directory on local drive works the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Windows search bar in `wp-content` directory and search for `companyName_apply_form`. You should find the file where the shortcode is created.

To add a shortcode in Wordpress you normally use this syntax:

```
'add_shortcode("shortcode_name", "function_name")'
```

Comment: I only have FTP access.

Comment: Download the `wp-content` directory locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have FTP access and you don't want to download the entire wp-content directory.

Try logging in via ssh and using grep in your wp-content directory:

```
grep -iRl "shortcode_name" ./
```